# Domain Name System architecture

Tags: networking, dns

I am having a difficult time visualizing the DNS architecture. I see that the DNS client contacts the DNS server which contacts a root server to start the name query. When I run `ipconfig /all` I see the the DNS Server IP the same as router.

Which entity is the DNS client and which is the DNS Server? Is my laptop the client and the router the server or is one of the components outside of my network and resides in the ISP network? If my router is the DNS server how does it know what the IP address of the root servers are?

Comment: It's "Domain Name System", by the way.

Answer (score 4):

The simple answer is that it depends.

From the perspective of your local network, your computer is the DNS client, and the router in your example is your DNS server that resolves any requests sent to it.

Where it gets tricky is that a DNS server can resolve addresses in more than one way. It can either completely handle resolving the address itself, for instance contacting the root etc like you mention, or it can forward the request to another DNS server.

On most local networks the latter is most common, which is why when setting up the router, one of the details you set are the DNS servers it should use. The router receives the request from your PC, then forwards that request to one of the DNS servers it has been configured with to get the answer. Once it receives that answer it will cache it locally, so if it receives another request for the same address within a set period (the TTL of the DNS record) either from your machine or another on the network, it can immediately respond without needing to do another lookup.

Note, the DNS server that the router queries may well do the same thing, eg simply forwarding the request on, or handle it itself.

More full on DNS servers will maintain the list of root DNS servers (currently on IPv4 DNS there are 13 of them), with the capacity to update that list through routine updates to BIND, Windows or whatever system they're running if those addresses changes (which they rarely do). Using that list they can handle the full process of resolving addresses themselves.

So you end up with DNS servers being split between DNS Forwarders and DNS Resolvers. Both will respond to a request for an address in the same way as far as the client is concerned, but the method they use to achieve that may differ.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation

Answer (score 2):

> When I run ipconfig /all I see the the DNS Server IP the same as router. Which entity is the DNS client and which is the DNS Server. Is my laptop the client and the router the server or is one of the components outside of my network and resides in the ISP network?

There can be more than two entities:

- Your laptop is the DNS client (a "stub resolver" that only supports talking to a single server);
- your router is a DNS server that only works as a caching proxy and forwards requests to another single server (generally your ISP's, or sometimes public servers);
- finally, your ISP runs a "recursive resolver" DNS server that does all of the querying from the root.

(And of course the DNS root servers themselves are… DNS servers; as are the ones that host zone data for various domains. Those are the "authoritative" servers.)

Because the router is just a proxy, you *could* skip it completely for the sake of simplicity and configure the laptop to directly act as a client to some resolver server. (Though you'd lose the router's "LAN domain" feature – that's one extra thing it does in addition to being a plain proxy.)

On the other hand, the router itself *could* technically be the 'server' (a full/recursive resolver) – it doesn't take much in terms of resources – but using the ISP-provided shared resolver with its already "warm" cache is far more efficient. So instead most home routers just do simple forwarding while adding their own local cache on top. But e.g. people who set up Pi-Hole with Unbound do have exactly that (Unbound has the ability to be a recursive resolver).

> If my router is the DNS server how does it know what the IP address of the root servers are?

Your router *usually* isn't the DNS server, but if it were, then it would come with the list of root servers already predefined.

The list changes infrequently enough that it can be included with the software itself (e.g. you'll find it embedded within Unbound or within BIND), and even when it does change, it'll still have 12 working entries until the next software update – it's enough to have just one working server from which the rest of the list can be refreshed. (The list is called the "root *hints* file" for that reason.)

Comment: Thank you for this explanation